# Elasticsearch - Dynamic mappings are not available on the node that holds the primary yet

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-rails

We have a rails application that is using the official elasticsearch gem to connect to elasticsearch.

I did a deploy which simply added one field (number) to the index (by editing the model + adding it to as_indexed_json) and would query by this field specifically in search.

A few minutes after the deploy load spiked very hard on one of the 3 servers in our Elasticsearch cluster. And then errors starting spamming in our log:

> Dynamic mappings are not available on the node that holds the primary
>   yet.

Searches started to get very, very slow, and eventually the cluster just failed entirely.

We had to force restart the cluster, and remove the code that added the field/search, and things started to work perfectly fine.

We did NOT do a PUT to update the mappings for the index, I was waiting for the first model index to basically do this.

Any ideas/pointers would be greatly appreciated.